# How can I make an Object utilize booleanValue() like Boolean?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, casting, boolean, wrapper

**In Java, the Boolean wrapper class contains a method called `booleanValue()` that returns the boolean primitive type of the value of the Boolean Object.**

The thing that interests me about this is that **the Java compiler recognizes this booleanValue() method and automatically adds it whenever a Boolean is used when a boolean is needed**; for example, if you write an if statement like `if (something)` where `something` is a Boolean Object, then compile the code and decompile the result, you'll see that the code now reads `if (something.booleanValue())`. It's almost like the compiler recognizes that the fact that the Boolean Object class has the booleanValue() method and automatically puts it in the same way that it can add `toString()` to the end of any Object added in a String addition expression.

So, my question is **how can I use this in a custom Object class?** Is there a way to make an Object class with a `booleanValue()` or `intValue()` method that is recognized by the compiler in the same way as with wrapper classes like Boolean and Integer?

I have found that the Boolean Object class only implements two interfaces: `Comparable<Boolean>` and `Serializable`. Since neither of these include a `booleanValue()` method, I don't understand how the Java compiler recognizes the `booleanValue()` method in the Boolean Object class and uses it the way it does. I tried simply making a `booleanValue()` method in my custom Object class and attempted to use the Object like a boolean, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key sentence in your question is

> that is recognized by the compiler

Unless you write your own compiler, you cannot make the compiler do anything. The fact that `booleanValue()` works is because the [Java Language Specification requires it.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> If `r` is a reference of type `Boolean`, then unboxing conversion converts `r` into `r.booleanValue()`

[The method `booleanValue` is declared in `java.lang.Boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#booleanValue%28%29).

Comment: So there's absolutely no way to make the compiler recognize another class the way is recognizes the Boolean class? There's no way to make this "unboxing conversion" take place with my own custom Object class?

Comment: @REALDrummer Not without rewriting your own compiler.

Comment: Curses. All right. Thanks for your help. I was hoping to use this method to make my code nicer by basically making the compiler cast for me, but I guess that won't work.

Comment: @REALDrummer Java is not very customizable that way.

Comment: Well, I just figured that they usually designate these sorts of things with a special interface or by making the object extend a specific standard Object class, but I couldn't find anything special in the Boolean class declaration, so I thought I might be missing something. Oh well. I'll keep searching for a good way to do it.